# Generated javadoc pages unneccesarily wrap method arguments with annotations

Tags: java, javadoc

If I generate javadoc for a method the method parameters/exceptions unnecessarily get wrapped into a new line, like this:

[image]

There is plenty of horizontal space left on the page. Using Oracle javadoc.exe 8u60.

**How can I prevent these unnecessary line breaks without having to manually edit the HTML files?**

This is the source code of the part shown in the screenshot:

```
<ul class="blockList">
    <li class="blockList">
        <a name="method.detail">
            <!--   -->
        </a>
        <h3>Method Detail</h3>
        <a name="getRootWord--">
            <!--   -->
        </a>
        <ul class="blockList">
            <li class="blockList">
                <h4>getRootWord</h4>
                <pre>@NotNull
public&nbsp;<a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html?is-external=true" title="class or interface in java.lang">String</a>&nbsp;getRootWord()</pre>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <a name="setRootWord-java.lang.String-">
            <!--   -->
        </a>
        <ul class="blockList">
            <li class="blockList">
                <h4>setRootWord</h4>
                <pre>public&nbsp;void&nbsp;setRootWord(@NotNull
                        <a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html?is-external=true" title="class or interface in java.lang">String</a>&nbsp;rootWord)</pre>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <a name="getAdjectiveDeclension--">
            <!--   -->
        </a>
        <ul class="blockList">
            <li class="blockList">
                <h4>getAdjectiveDeclension</h4>
                <pre>@NotNull
public&nbsp;<a href="../../../../com/kayon/core/adjective/AdjectiveDeclension.html" title="interface in com.kayon.core.adjective">AdjectiveDeclension</a>&nbsp;getAdjectiveDeclension()
                                                     throws <a href="../../../../com/kayon/core/NoDeclensionException.html" title="class in com.kayon.core">NoDeclensionException</a></pre>
                <dl>
                    <dt><span class="throwsLabel">Throws:</span></dt>
                    <dd><code><a href="../../../../com/kayon/core/NoDeclensionException.html" title="class in com.kayon.core">NoDeclensionException</a></code></dd>
                </dl>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <a name="setAdjectiveDeclension-com.kayon.core.adjective.AdjectiveDeclension-">
            <!--   -->
        </a>
        <ul class="blockList">
            <li class="blockList">
                <h4>setAdjectiveDeclension</h4>
                <pre>public&nbsp;void&nbsp;setAdjectiveDeclension(@Nullable
                                   <a href="../../../../com/kayon/core/adjective/AdjectiveDeclension.html" title="interface in com.kayon.core.adjective">AdjectiveDeclension</a>&nbsp;adjectiveDeclension)</pre>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The source code above is extracted, condensed and processed by a HTML formatter for easier reading, [here is the very raw complete file](https://gist.github.com/RAnders00/cdb94887150e339f36fa).

Comment: So you already have an HTML formatter but you don't know how to use it?

Comment: I used a online quick HTML formatter to make it easier to read, the original and the inline code basically equal. Nothing more then that.

Comment: Are you up to using doclets to get around this problem? It's doable, but a lot of effort for a comparatively small change.

Comment: @approxiblue It's not worth it IMO. I would just stick with the small issues rather than spending lots of time on it.

Comment: Okay. For reference, if you look at the source of the jdk8u60 tools.jar which generates javadoc, they [add a new line after every method parameter annotation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/langtools/file/d56703662c0f/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/doclets/formats/html/AbstractExecutableMemberWriter.java#l209).

Comment: @approxiblue So I guess if I wanted to I could ASM it away, if I really wanted to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can customise the format of your javadoc by writing a custom doclet.

Please check this section in the javadoc generator documentation:

> **Javadoc Doclets**
>
> You can customize the content and format of the javadoc command output with doclets. The javadoc command has a default built-in doclet, called the standard doclet, that generates HTML-formatted API documentation. You can modify or make a subclass of the standard doclet, or write your own doclet to generate HTML, XML, MIF, RTF or whatever output format you want.
>
> When a custom doclet is not specified with the -doclet option, the javadoc command uses the default standard doclet. The javadoc command has several options that are available regardless of which doclet is being used. The standard doclet adds a supplementary set of command-line options. See Options.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html

Comment: Re-implementing the entire doclet for just getting rid of a few line breaks is a tough solution…